# matlab - graph plottion with unit step function

Tags: matlab

i want to plot `x=(a^n)*u(n)` in matlab. Here is the code:
`u(n)` here represents the unit step function.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
a = input('Enter variable:');
n=[-7:1:7];
for i=1:size(n,2)
    if(n(i) > 1)
       x(i)=a.^n(i);
    else
        x(i)=0;
    end
end
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(n(i),x(i));
title('function x(n)');
xlabel('n value');
ylabel('x value');
```

When i execute the code, it is not showing the desired output. Please help.

Comment: You can create your array `x` as: `a.^n.*(n>a)`. No loop needed.

Answer (score 3):

It's only plotting one data point:

```
plot(n(i),x(i));
```

replace that with

```
plot(n,x);
```

As you can see, this inputs the whole vector `n` and `x` instead of just the `i`th element `x(i)` and `n(i)`.